# If - else statement inside a vue event listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

Is there a way to accomplish this in vue:

```
<button @click="(true) ? funcA : FuncB">
Click
</button>
```

In this case, the event is a click, but it could be a keypress, keydown, input and whatever else is on the vuejs docs.

If that's just not possible, what's the best way to accomplish the above without doing code repetition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an arrow function like :

```
@click="()=>{(true) ? funcA() : FuncB()}"
```

Comment: It actually worked but only if I add the parenthesis with the function, do you know why is that?

Comment: you should execute the methods by adding the () because the click event has already a handler which is the arrow function `()=>`,